# QT qmake lowercases my custom widget names

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

I'm using QT 4.6 on Linux and Windows, and on Linux, it insists on including my QScrollPane by qscrollpane.h

App.pro:

```
HEADERS += widgets/QScrollPane.h
```

The section from mainform.ui

> ```
> <widget class="QScrollPane" name="ListView">
>  <property name="geometry">
>   <rect>
>    <x>0</x>
>    <y>0</y>
>    <width>500</width>
>    <height>490</height>
>   </rect>
>  </property>
> </widget>
> ```

The ui_mainform.h file:

```
 #include <QtGui/QStatusBar>
 #include <QtGui/QTabWidget>
 #include <QtGui/QWidget>
 #include <qscrollpane.h>
```

This isn't a big deal on Windows or Mac, but on Linux it's downright annoying.  I could create a symlink to solve the issue, but I want to find the root cause.

Regards,
-Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide more info about your custom widget. Add the following to your mainform.ui:

```
<customwidgets>
 <customwidget>
  <class>QScrollPane</class>
  <extends>QWidget or whatever class is QScrollPane parent</extends>
  <header>QScrollPane.h</header>
 </customwidget>
</customwidgets>
```

Should do the trick (disclaimer: tested only on Windows Qt 4.6.1).

I prefer using all lowercase filenames for my classes - I'm always 100% sure I won't be screwed up by some non 100% cross-platform tool.

Comment: good advice on the lowercase filenames.  I'm considering that.